# htaccess - how to redirect /q/<id> to /#/q/<id>?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my Rewrite Rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule "^/q/(a-zA-Z0-9)*/?$" "/#/q/$1"
```

Something does not work, I don't understand what.

I want to redirect /q/xxx to /#/q/xxx

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution: `RewriteRule ^q/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /#/q/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]`

The flags were missing